# loading images to show them offline

Tags: javascript, html, css, offline

I've made a web application that manages the offline state if the user loses their connection. For this, I show information/error/... messages to the user to inform about the offline state.

My problem is that some icons or images in the warning messages are not shown because they are loaded when the user already has lost the connection...
The images are in the CSS not in the html :

```
.warning
{
background: #FFE680 url(../images/ico_warning.png) no-repeat 10px center / 18px;
}
```

How can I preload the images/icons at the page construction to use them offline ?

N.B : I can't use the HTML5 offline functionality (manifest) because my targeted users are on IE9 (html5 manifest is not supported) and for personal reasons I can't use sprites...

Thanks for your help

Comment: hack: Attach a hidden div to the your page with the img tag. Using javscript pull out that image when you detect offline state.

Comment: OK seem's to work with this kind of hack. But I didn't want to add unused element directly in the page, so I initialized the messagebox with all img in the content. When the message is displayed, I replace the whole content of the box with my message, so the images are not shown. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,
I found a way to load the image offline.
Because the CSS is fully loaded in any case, if I put the image in the CSS as a base64 string, it won't need a connection to show it.

Here is an exemple

```
.warning{
background: #FFE680 url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA_complete_base64_string_here...') no-repeat 10px center / 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to assign the needed images as `background-image` to the elements that are present on a page. Like headers or sidebars (if they don't have images as backgrounds of course).

The trick will be to set the `background-repeat` property to `no-repeat` and `background-position` to `-999em -999em`. Thus the images will be downloaded but visually hidden.

Comment: Hello, I tried with this solution, but I thought it was not appropriate in my case. With this solution I will "pollute" the CSS because I have multiple images... Anyway thanks for your reply.

Comment: yep, you either "pollute" your html or css.. up to you :) I prefer my variant because it doesn't need any special html elements or any javascript magic