Load a web page (HTML,CSS,JS) offline on Android Tablet
I developed a simple website that I need to use as a tool offline, it works fine when the device I use is connected online but I need to use it without any internet connection.
Its simple but the problems I have encountered:

Some images are loaded with javascript so they get refreshed everytime when I lose connection it stops working (caching, preloading doesnt help)
When I copied the whole folder with the files that contanins everything in the android device (tablet) only the index.html gets loaded (the images, js, css are all relative linked).

The website its a game/poll like. Doesnt perform any task with mandatory internet connection.
I tried downloading using chrome to access later but Javascript doesnt work.
The copied version of the website doesnt work on mobile devices, on laptops and desktops they work fine. Also when accessing the website with the android device it works fine.

This wasn't clear from your question, but I highly suggest using a dedicated HTML editing app that allows you to load packages. Also, in the short-term, try using file paths instead of links. Links often get routed through the web unless the compiler knows to look through your files. Hope this works.

Thanks, What I have are some 'screens' all of them in the index.html main file, but they are hidden (css: display:none;) when I show them the images get loaded, as I specified sometimes I have no internet connection, so  they dont load, even when they where previously loaded. I have tried using something like: display:hidden, opacity:0, preloading them with <link rel='preload'.... but none of them work, When the images get called or updated using javascript they fail to load, the paths to the images are relative so the are not specified like <img src='https://'...

@EstebanNaranjo see if anything here can help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713360/loading-images-to-show-them-offline
